# log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "testAppender"

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Here is my log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,console,defaultAppender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n


log4j.appender.defaultAppender=x.y.z.DefaultAppender
log4j.appender.defaultAppender.layout = x.y.z.JsonLayout
log4j.appender.defaultAppender.File=defaultmodule
log4j.appender.defaultAppender.Append=true

log4j.category.x.y.z.App=INFO, applicationAppender, testAppender
log4j.appender.applicationAppender=x.y.z.TestLog4jHandler
log4j.appender.applicationAppender.layout=x.y.z.JsonLayout
log4j.appender.applicationAppender.File=appmodule
log4j.appender.applicationAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.applicationAppender.MaxBackupIndex = 10

log4j.appender.testAppender=x.y.z.Log4j2Appender
log4j.appender.testAppender.layout=x.y.z.JsonLayout
log4j.appender.testAppender.File=appmodule
log4j.appender.testAppender.Append=true
```

While using this props in my application , it throws error saying:
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "testAppender".

is there any thing i am doing wrong?

Comment: Not definitive, but: it seems that you are mixing log4j (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/, as indicated by the name of the config file: "log4j.properties") with log4j2 (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html, as indicated by the name of the testAppender class: "x.y.z.Log4j2Appender"). AFAIK you cannot use a Log4j2-appender with log4j 1.2.

Comment: @ThomasKläger can i convert existing log4j.properties to log4j2 props?

Comment: If you are using log4j then migrating the configuration properties is not enough. You will need to change your application to use log4j2 (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)

Comment: That's right and same I have done but still no logs getting created but earlier error is gone. Can you plz give provide ur inout on what can be the log4j2 props of above configuration